# How to use and, when & thenDo operators in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

I'm trying to learn RxJS v5, and I saw `and` `when` and `thenDo` operators in the manual. I'm struggling to understand how they work.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/and-then-when.html

I tried the following code to combine my 2 observables:

```
this.ob1 = Rx.Observable.interval(500);
this.ob2 = Rx.Observable.interval(750);

this.combined = Rx.Observable.when(
    this.ob1.and(this.ob2).thenDo((first, second) => {
        return {first, second}
    })
);

this.combined.subscribe(e => console.log('observable ' + e));
```

However, I get the following error:
`TypeError: this.ob1.and is not a function`

What am I doing wrong here? How are these operators supposed to be used? And what's the specific use case they would solve.